# Redux-Persist - Multi Tab Logout

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-persist

I am using redux-persist for my react/redux application to give the multi-tab and page refresh support, which happens seamlessly. Now the issue is :

1. I login
2. I open multiple tabs
3. Logout from one tab
4. Expected: Logged out only from that tab (JWT)
5. What happens is: REHYDRATE happens on other tabs on page refresh and my state is persisted.

I tried using the redux-persist-crosstab but seems like they are not compatible with the latest version. what is a gracious way of handling LOGOUT with redux-persist in MULTI Tab scenario?

Comment: Hey Gauri! Did you find the answer? If so, please do let me know. I need help for the same.